# Linkedin connections search first job title for each connection

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get all the current job titles of my connections from linkedin. I managed to do it but only by requesting ALL jobtitles and then grabbing the first one. That's inefficient. 
I'm doing something simmillar to this:

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "positions:(title)"])
    .result(function(result) { ($"#profile").html(JSON.stringify(result))} );
}
```

I know I can add a param and get a count of lets say 5 (.params({"count": 10...)) but that only seems to work for connections not titles of connections...I've tried "positions:(title)[0]" but it did not work.

Any thoughts? is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the current job, you need to request the `is-current` [field](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#positions) as well. Then simply iterate through the returned `positions` collection checking the is-current value for each position. Your call would be:

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "positions:(title,isCurrent)"])
    .result(function(result) { ($"#profile").html(JSON.stringify(result))} );
}
```